# Enable a drupal module in website

Tags: drupal-7, hybridauth

I am pretty new to Drupal. I can understand its flexibilities of the modules provided by Drupal. But I don't understand how to add them to the website.

At the moment I'm trying to add social login module to my website (HybridAuth), just for testing, I managed to finish configuration (downloading module, customize module setting, etc.)

But I have no idea how to add it to my website, display it to the homepage, it could be anywhere, I just need to understand the steps because I can't really find it when I went google. Can someone show me how to do that?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need/want the login block to appear. Go to "admin/structure/block", look for "User login" and put that block in the region of your choice. More info here: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work at all. The HybridAuth module does work when I click on it in my profile page. But it just isn't shown on my side bar ...

Answer (score 0):

Check with admin/structure/block here you can find a block for social login and user login . You only need to assign that block in the desired region. That's it.